# C++ reassign pointer then delete it

Tags: c++, pointers

Is this safe and correct? I mean does the delete care only about the address it is given or is it important to delete the original pointer variable?

```
myClass *p1 = new myClass();
myClass *p2 = p1;
delete p2;
p1 = NULL;
p2 = NULL;
```

Comment: `int *p1 = new myClass();` Unless `myClass` is a typedef for `int`, how can this possibly work?

Comment: sorry, i used int initially, post edited

Answer (score 6):

Delete only cares about the *address*, so your code is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this safe and correct?

It *works*. That is, it has well-defined behaviour and doesn't leak (assuming it compiles).

But safe? It is a *dangerous* idea to have aliased pointers running around free. You have to track which pointers have been deleted and which aren't; which point to memory that was deleted and which don't.

It's much safer to use RAII-enabled handles to manage your dynamically allocated objects, like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` (or boost replacements). `std::unique_ptr` doesn't allow aliasing, and `std::shared_ptr` allows aliasing in a safe manner.

Answer (score 3):

Since p1 and p2 point to the same object, then if you `delete` it through p2, you will also have deleted what pointed p1 to. So this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine.  You allocated memory to p1, then referenced the SAME memory in p2.  When you called delete on p2, the memory that p1 was also deleted (they're the same thing, location and all).  It's also correct that you set them both to NULL, as deleting p1 otherwise after that may have caused some problems since it was no longer pointing to valid memory.